# React Native stretch row items?

Tags: react-native, styling

I have to buttons next to each other in a view
For some reason even if I setting the View to alignItems: 'stretch' or set the items alignSelf: 'stretch' they won't use up the available space. How could I solve this?

For example:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'stretch'}}>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', height: 100}}/>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', height: 100}}/>
</View>
```

The views won't stretch, and the inside elements will stay with width: 0

or same with the Button items:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'stretch'}}>
    <Button title='text' style={{backgroundColor: 'red', 
    height: 100}}/>
    <Button title='text' style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', 
    height: 100}}/>
</View>
```

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: added some update

Comment: You could add **flex: 1** to the container view, and if that does not work it is the parent of that view which is restricting the size

Comment: Nope not working, and there isn't a parent. Its a scene itself for test.

Answer (score 6):

You need to give **width** to main view. So you can set button based on it. Also, you need to set **flex** for each button.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width:'100%', flex:1}}>
    <Button title='text' style={{backgroundColor: 'red', 
    height: 100, flex:1}}/>
    <Button title='text' style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', 
    height: 100, flex:1}}/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just realise you are using alignItems, while you should be using justifyContent to spread your items over the main axis (horizontal in your case). Stretch is no option for justifyContent so you could choose space-between or space-evenly for instance:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', height: 100}}/>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', height: 100}}/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the Buttons in an additional `View` component:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
    <View style = {{flex: 1}}>
        <Button title="Button 1" />
    </View>
    <View style = {{flex: 1}}>
       <Button title="Button 2" />
    </View>
</View>
```

Or use the `Text` component along with `TouchableOpacity`:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row"}}>
    <TouchableOpacity style = {{width: "50%"}}>
        <Text style={{textAlign:"center"}} > Button 1 </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style = {{width: "50%"}}>
        <Text style={{textAlign:"center"}} > Button 1 </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Try out both solutions here: https://snack.expo.io/wAENhUQrp

- `justifyContent: 'space-between'` doesn't use all available space for the buttons
- `button {alignSelf: 'stretch'}` doesn't work on the Button component

Answer (score 0):

Use this style simply!

> `style={{flexDirection: 'row',alignSelf: 'stretch',}}`